# How to check if values are equal

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to check if the value matches too another value. I tried this code but it doesnt work it always gives me doesnt match. Someone got an idea how i can check for it oder a method? Thank you guys!

```
DatabaseReference CheckULobby = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID).child("Lobby");
CheckULobby.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        final String getULobby = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        DatabaseReference CheckFLobby = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(post_UserID).child("Lobby");

        CheckFLobby.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String getFLobby = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                if(getFLobby == getULobby){
                    Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else{
                     Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "doesnt match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You should try outputting your results. You can do that by writing to the log:

    Log.i("Val A", getFlobby);
    Log.i("Val B", getULobby.

Comment: Please visit google .This kind of questions already asked .

Comment: Im sry im new here at stackoverflow and i searched the wrong way

Answer (score 0):

Use `String` method `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`:

```
if(getFLobby.equals(getULobby)){
  Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
  Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "doesnt match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

OR

```
if(getFLobby.equalsIgnoreCase(getULobby)){
  Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "matches", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
  Toast.makeText(CreateLobby.this, "doesnt match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I tried it already doesnt work but i will try it again

Comment: Ouh nice it works :3 But if Lobby doesnt exist in the friend database it crashes hm...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
getFLobby.equals(getULobby)
```